# Всплывающее окно на сайте в IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Нем могу понять в чем проблема, во всех браузерах нормально работает, а в IE нет. Суть проблемы, блок появляется и через секунду сразу исчезает, такое только в EI.

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#reg').click(function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    $('#regBox').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });

            $('#boxclose').click(function(){
                $('#regBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: [mcve] в виде сниппета?

Comment: Тут посмотрите https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/

Еще как вариант переписать на CSS и использовать метод  addClass('yourCssClass')